# Git: how can I exclude just one branch from push?

Tags: git, privacy, git-branch

I'd like to continue to push (almost) all branches with a simple `git push` command, but there are a few things I'd like to be able to keep in Git locally without sharing them with the  rest of the world.

The things I'm keeping locally include *private changes* to *public files*—hence, I'd like to keep the secret stuff in an appropriately named branch that doesn't get pushed to the server. Is this a thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just create branches in some namespace like `private` - `git checkout -b private/mybranch`. As long as that namespace is not existing on the remote repo, any branch in that namespace will not be pushed when you do `git push`

To also prevent pushing by explicit, set the `branch.<name>.remote` to some some nonexistent  remote.

Comment: Thank you, that was precisely it! Well, almost. I had configured git to push _all_ branches at some point—which, I'm afraid, I don't remember doing—so I had to take the extra step of _turning that off_,  but now everything's set.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to push more than one branch at a time is by using push.default = matching, [described as](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html): "push all matching branches. All branches having the same name in both ends are considered to be matching." That's the default setting, so maybe what you're used to. You can have a branch not pushed by naming it something that doesn't exist on the remote you're pushing to.

Comment: I accepted the other answer because it goes further by offering a "just in case" safety net, but thank you for pointing out `push.default`! I would totally accept this answer too if I could accept more than one. C: