# git equivalent for mercurials phases feature for preventing a branch to be pushed

Tags: git, mercurial

I am currently facing the problem that we need to shift to git due some decisions made by other people.

So with mercurial we have the great phases feature, which allows me to manage local branches which will be ignored when a push(all) is issued. The great advantage is, the phases feature is independent from the server hosted master repositories. I can use it on my own locally without permission from anyone.

with git, as far as web search told me, you can add some hooks with branch filtering to common server hosted master repositories. My problem is: as a developer I do not have any control other than create/delete/push/pull. I can not install any hooks there and the people managing the servers will never tinker around with them by hand manually. Everything is managed by an ALM software.

So the solutions for git I found in the Web are not an option for my problem.

This leads to my question: is there any other mechanism in git, which can replace the functionality of mercurial phases, which enables me on a local repository to prevent some branches from ever being pushed to a server hosted repository?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7424182/3001761?

Comment: Sadly, Git is quite lacking here. Your main option is the one in the linked answer: don't use a *branch* name (potentially painful—how much pain depends on that other software). (Another simple option is to just have two clones: one that you let them see, and one that you don't.)

Comment: Thx, the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/q/7424182/3001761 at least seems to be feasable enougth to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've always been able to explicitly configure what refspecs get pushed or fetched when you don't give explicit specs on on the command line, and since v2.29 that includes negative matches.

To push all matching branches to origin but not branch notthisone,

```
git config --unset-all remote.origin.push
git config --add remote.origin.push :
git config --add remote.origin.push ^refs/heads/notthisone
```

and from then on a plain

```
git push
```

will push all matching branches, except not `nottthisone` even if it matches.

I see the `git push` docs weren't updated to reflect the new feature, push and fetch both use the same engine for handling the patterns, I just tried the above sequence and it works as advertised.

Here's the config file from my test:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "t2"]
    url = ../t2
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/t2/*
    push = :
    push = ^refs/heads/b2
```

Comment: Ah, I had forgotten that this feature was actually out now. It does seem to have been kind of flaky, so I'll still hold off on recommending it, though.

Comment: @jthill do you have a link or so, to some documentation how to do the git config steps by hand in the config file... for my personal taste, editing the config by hand is what I want. I don't understand why I need a tool for automated editing of a textfile...

Comment: Sure, the multivalue stuff is just ... multiple values. I added my test sample config. `git help config` shows the full syntax.

Comment: thx... now I just need to wait for git v2.29 to arrive at work :-) maybe in the next 1-2 years